# My guessing game is not working as my expectation: my if else statement doesn't work

Tags: python

```
secret_element = "Oxygen"

guess = ""

amount = 3

element = {

     "A" : "Nitrogen",

     "B" : "Krypton",

     "C" : "Xenon",

     "D" : "Helium",

     "E" : "fluorine",

     "F" : "Lithium",

     "G" : "Oxygen"

    }

b = 0

while b < 3:

    print("Insert alphabet A, B, C, D, E, F or G to find the element")

    guess = str(input("All you need is luck\n"))

if guess != secret_element:

    b += 1

    amount -= 1

    print(amount, "attempt left\neLPOZO")

else:

    print("Congrats,you got the right one!" ,secret_element,"!")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Your `if`/`else` statement is outside of the loop.  So you have an infinite loop followed by an `if`/`else` that is never reached.  Indent the `if`/`else` to place it in the loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

there it is:

```
secret_element = "Oxygen"

guess = ""

amount = 3

element = {

     "A" : "Nitrogen",

     "B" : "Krypton",

     "C" : "Xenon",

     "D" : "Helium",

     "E" : "fluorine",

     "F" : "Lithium",

     "G" : "Oxygen"

    }

b = 0

while b < 3:

    print("Insert alphabet A, B, C, D, E, F or G to find the element")

    guess = str(input("All you need is luck\n"))

    if element[guess] != secret_element:

        b += 1

        amount -= 1

        print(amount, "attempt left\neLPOZO")

    else:

        print("Congrats,you got the right one!" ,secret_element,"!")
```